# GetUserName under MacOSX with Lazarus FPC

Tags: macos, cross-platform, lazarus, fpc

i'm right now porting an application which was made for Window using Lazarus to MacOSX.

I've a few WinAPI calls which i need to recode to make it work under Mac.

Now i need to find out the user name of the current mac account which is logged in the OS.

Any idea's how i do this under MacOSX with lazarus?

greetings

Answer (score 1):

The users package has various useraccount related routines for *nix.

```
uses users,baseunix;

begin
  Writeln(GetUserName(fpgetuid));
end.
```